# Combination of Rvalue binding and moving

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

I have to following piece of code and I wanted to know what the standard says about it. Is it undefined behaviour, defined but unspecified behaviour or well-defined behaviour?

```
using namespace std;

struct Foo {
    mutable int obj;
    Foo(Foo&&) = default;
    Foo(int arg) : obj(arg) {}
    void f() const { obj *= 2; }
};

int main()
{
    Foo&& a = Foo(5); // Binds temporary, lifetime ends with program
    const Foo& b = a; // Binds a, lifetime ends with program
    Foo c(std::move(a)); // Moves from a
    // a now in defined, but unspecified state
    b.f(); // ??
    cout << b.obj << endl; // May output 10
    return 0;
} // End of lifetime of temporary
```

Are the annotations and my understanding and interpretation of the standard correct?

Comment: Why on earth would that be undefined behaviour? The moved-from state of a scalar is exactly equivalent to the state before the move. It's a copy.

Comment: The "valid but unspecified state" is a convention, followed by most standard library classes, about how their move operations affect the moved-from object. There's nothing unspecified about the compiler-generated move constructor, or the state of a moved-from `Foo`.

Comment: @T.C. Ah, so that is where I misinterpreted the standard... well it isn't quite easy to read

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`move`ing from a value (rvalue ref construction, not calling `std::move`, naturally) semantically means that the value should be in a valid (specifically, valid for destruction) but unspecified state.

However, `move` in C++ does not do magic.  This is just what you *should* do, not what the language forces you to do.

`move`ing a primitive "scalar" type instance does nothing different than copying it.

`move`ing class types does a member-wise (and parent-wise) `move` of each component from the source to the destination.

The `=default` just means "use the move constructor of my elements", which is an `int`, and the move constructor of `int` does ... a copy (well, the move constructor of `int` doesn't exist, but if it did it would do a copy).

The semantic meaning of `move`, that you must leave the source in a valid (and most importantly destroyable) state, is required to interact with `std` containers and algorithms in reasonable ways, and is how `std` types behave.

---

All that is well and good, but where is the standard backing?

What happens when you `move` using `=default` a class in this case ends up with this clause:

## [class.copy]/15.3

> otherwise, the base or member is direct-initialized with the corresponding base or member of x

And for direct-initialization, the clause that tells you how to direct-initialize an `int` from an `int&&` is:

## [dcl.init]/17.8

> Otherwise, the initial value of the object being initialized is the (possibly converted) value of the ini-tializer expression.

The value of the second expression `int a = 7; std::move(a);` is 7.  The value of `a` is not changed, because the standard does not permit it.

Moving isn't magic.

(Quotes from [n4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf), the current draft standard.)